# how to use Oracle dbms_scheduler to run procedure every 5 minutes, every day from 7:30am to 21:30pm?

Tags: database, oracle, scheduler

I am using oracle 12c DB. I must schedule a procedure to run every 5 minutes every day from 7:30am to 21:30pm. 
Procedure actualy runs every day from 08:00 to 20:55

```
begin
dbms_scheduler.create_job(
job_name=>'JobInvioSmsVa',
job_type=>'plsql_block',
repeat_interval=> 'FREQ=DAILY;BYHOUR=8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20;BYMINUTE=0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55',
job_action=>'INVIO_SMS_VA;',
enabled=>true);
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply:

```
  begin
    dbms_scheduler.create_job(
    job_name=>'JobInvioSmsVa',
    job_type=>'plsql_block',
    repeat_interval=> 'FREQ=DAILY;BYHOUR=7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21;BYMINUTE=0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55',
    job_action=>
     'begin
       if sysdate 
         between trunc(sysdate)+7.5/24 
         and trunc(sysdate)+21.5/24 
       then
         INVIO_SMS_VA;
       end if;  
     end;',
    enabled=>true);
    end;
    /
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create three schedules:

```
begin

dbms_scheduler.create_job(
   job_name=>'JobInvioSmsVa',
   job_type=>'plsql_block',
   repeat_interval=> 'FREQ=DAILY;BYHOUR=8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20;BYMINUTE=0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55',
   job_action=>'INVIO_SMS_VA;',
   enabled=>true);

dbms_scheduler.create_job(
   job_name=>'JobInvioSmsVa_morning',
   job_type=>'plsql_block',
   repeat_interval=> 'FREQ=DAILY;BYHOUR=7;BYMINUTE=30,35,40,45,50,55',
   job_action=>'INVIO_SMS_VA;',
   enabled=>true);

dbms_scheduler.create_job(
   job_name=>'JobInvioSmsVa_evening',
   job_type=>'plsql_block',
   repeat_interval=> 'FREQ=DAILY;BYHOUR=21;BYMINUTE=0,5,10,15,20,25,30',
   job_action=>'INVIO_SMS_VA;',
   enabled=>true);

end;

/
```

The `INCLUDE` clause cannot be used in combination with `BYHOUR` or `BYMINUTE`, thus you cannot combine them into a single schedule.